# will zero loss affect back propagation update

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, backpropagation

Say I'm doing a standard DNN classification task, and I'm using the cross-entropy loss. After loss calculation, I apply a mask vector([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...] to the loss to set some of the loss to zero.
the question is how will Tensorflow handle this zero loss? Will it be involved in back propagation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, tensorflow will be able to handle this. The gradients leading to the masked loss values will then just be 0 because they did not influence the loss values.

Comment: Thanks Marc, How will tensorflow handle this? will tensorflow just throw the samples whose loss masked to zero? and why? note that the loss=0 does not mean the gradient=0

Comment: Loss=0 does not mean gradient=zero, but the gradient is zero if a variable has no influence on the outcome of your loss function. If you mask your loss values with zero values, then they block any influence of your model variables on the outcome of your loss and thus the gradient is zero. It is the same as applying dropout in a neural network. There you block some values by multiplying by 0 as well, and no gradient flows through this operation.

Comment: Thanks Marc, i gain some sense of your explanation(may still missed some points). but there is tiny difference, in my case, the mask operation applies to input samples not graph variables(one loss corresponds to one sample). do the different samples share the same TF graph(and same graph variables)? if so, how will TF block the update?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mean that within one batch you calculate the loss for many samples and then mask out some of the calculated loss values, so that the loss for some of the samples is zero? If this is the case, then these samples for which you masked out the loss values will just not contribute to your gradient and the gradient is only calculated on the basis of the other samples. As always remember: Everything that does not contribute to the final loss value will have no gradient. Applying a mask basically "disconnects" some weights/samples from your loss.

Comment: thanks for your reply. your understanding is correct. And I get what you mean totally now. But still how TF make sure it will "disconnects" the zero loss samples? is this from math definition or TF has some "magic" logic in the backend?

Comment: The reason why tensorflow is able to handle this is because you have to build you whole model and your whole loss function out of tensorflow functions (and not e.g. numpy or something else). This is because tensorflow internallly knows the gradient for every function it lets you use, and can thus calculate the overall gradients of your model by combining all of the individual gradients of the individual functions using the usual backpropagation rules.

Comment: Thanks @Marc, what's the normal "TF" way to do such mask operation so that it will achieve the effect you mentioned above?

Comment: The way I would do it is to just create an array of 0s and 1s and multiply it by the error values. This assumes that you know which values to mask beforehand. If you want to do this, then just include the mask in your y_actual of your loss function and apply it in your loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Applying a mask to the loss of your model after you have calculated the actual loss essentially means that the zero elements of the gradient are omitted during backward propagation. For example, it is a very common approach to apply a mask vector to the loss when dealing with time series data, which is usually padded to have the same length. These extra zero values are of no use to your model when calculating your gradients and are therefore ignored.

Comment: Thanks AloneTogether. I have no experience in dealing time series with deep learning. Do you mean Tensorflow will throw those samples with 0 loss? But loss=0 doesn't mean gradient=0, how will tensorflow manage to throw those 0-loss samples? what if it actually have a non-zero gradient?

Comment: Hi @AloneTogether, I am using masked loss for my timeseries data but I am not sure how to analyse the model output. can you point me to any source where masked loss has been used? thanks